# Delete trigger MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I use trigger `DELETE AFTER` in MySQL when user deletes article.

This trigger copies deleted row to another clone table.

But I have issue, how to set user id, who deleted this article when I copy row after delete?

I know user id only in server side and only when action happens.

I assume I should create procedure where pass deleted article and user id, what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more common way of doing this is not to copy to another table, but to have something like a `deleted_at` timestamp column on the table (and `deleted_by` to store the user ID), and to add `WHERE deleted_at IS NULL` to your queries.

This is often termed "soft deletion" and is a lot easier to manage than a copy of the table.

Comment: I know, but I also need store operation type, I dont want create a new field in each  table where I delete

Comment: A complete copy of every table (and having to mirror schema changes, and copy data back and forth) is **lots** more work than adding a new field.

Comment: Anyway I need to log who made changes ans what operation, not only change status

Comment: Having a copy of the table won't accomplish that. An audit log is a separate issue, and should typically be handled by a totally new table. See http://laravel-auditing.com/ for a great example of a well-implemented one.

Comment: I need simple solution, just store action id and user id

Comment: I'm suggesting the simple solution. Managing procedures and clones of database tables is the *complicated* solution.

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest to use php/js or whatever language you are using to apply this business logic. But if you want to keep this in MySQL you could add column "deleted_from" in the table and the clone table and set this column before deleting the row.